# How to make an AngularJS scope variable dependent on media query with EnquireJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, responsive-design, angular-ui

The goal is to make an Angular scope variable dependent on the screen resolution. I found that the EnquireJS library does just that. The final working result should be that the menu collapses when screen is 480px, based on an `isCollapsed` variable. (I'm using Angular-ui from bootstrap) Note: I must use Angular.

I can attach the Angular scope variable (`isCollapsed`) to the Javascript $window and address the $window in EnquireJS, this is what I have.

Create module + controller and attach scope + window

```
angular.module('PremiumMeat', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('PremiumMeat').controller('CollapseCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
$scope.isCollapsed = false;
$window.collapsed = false;
});
```

Enquire setup, initialize variable on `false`

```
// Enquire configuration
var enquireQuery= "screen and (max-width:480px)";
var enquireQueryHandler = {
setup: function () {
    $scope.isCollapsed = false;

    $window.collapsed = false;
    angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="CollapseCtrl"]')).scope().isCollapsed=false;
},
```

The `isCollapsed` variable should be initialized on `false` and become `true` when screen size reaches 480px;
I'm trying to address the variable through the `$window` and both the `document` object, but none work.

```
match: function () {
    $scope.isCollapsed = true;

    $window.collapsed = true;
    angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="CollapseCtrl"]')).scope().isCollapsed=true;
},
unmatch: function () {
    $scope.isCollapsed = false;

    $window.collapsed = false;
    angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="CollapseCtrl"]')).scope().isCollapsed=false;
}
};
```

Now the question is where to initialize the enquireJS to make it all work.

```
enquire.register(enquireQuery, enquireQueryHandler, true);
```

When I put it in the `controller` it stops working and outside it, it doesn't overrule.

Final working result should be that the menu collapses when screen is 480px. Note: I must use Angular (angular-ui bootstrap)

Comment: Never used EnquireJS, anyway $scope and $window are valid only inside angular flow, you can't use it in an external js library. Maybe getting the scope from the element can work, but angular doesnt know something happened and will not $apply your scope changes. I would try another approach: triggering some event. Take a look at this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/oHd8fOX6J8Y). Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I created a service to handle EnquireJS media queries in my Angular application that might be of use to you: https://gist.github.com/schuyberg/034a9982bf8326c19fc9

For your case here, the service would look something like this:

```
services.factory('max480', ['$rootScope', '$timeout', function ($rootScope, $timeout) {
    var max480 = {
        watch: function() { enquire.register('screen and (max-width: 480px)', max480handler); },
        unwatch: function() { enquire.unregister('screen and (max-width: 480px)'); },
        ismatch: function(callback) { $rootScope.$on('match480', callback); },
        notmatch: function(callback) { $rootScope.$on('unmatch480', callback); },
    };
    var max480handler = {
        match: function() {
            $timeout(function(){
                $rootScope.$emit('match480');
            });
        },
        unmatch: function(){
            $rootScope.$emit('unmatch480');
        }
    };
    return max480;
}]);
```

Then, inject the service in your controller, and use the following to register the enquire listener, and act on changes:

```
// this setup can live in your controller
$scope.isCollapsed = false;
$window.collapsed = false;
angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng controller="CollapseCtrl"]')).scope().isCollapsed=false;

// use the service to listen for, and react to changes
max480.watch();
max480.ismatch(function(){
    $scope.isCollapsed = true;
    $window.collapsed = true;
    angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="CollapseCtrl"]')).scope().isCollapsed=true;
});
max480.notmatch(function(){
    $scope.isCollapsed = false;
    $window.collapsed = false;
    angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="CollapseCtrl"]')).scope().isCollapsed=false;
});
```

This service has the advantage of being reusable throughout your application. You can also use `max480.unwatch();` to unregister the listener if you need to.